# How do I cut up a dataframe using dates as the start and end points?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I am using DataFrame.iloc to cut my dataframe into small dataframes based on integer position.

```
#df_all is my full dataframe that includes a column for date and time 
df_some = df_all.iloc[100:4000]
```

However, when I use this method, I have to guess the integer values until I get the correct start and end dates. Is there a method I can use to split up my data frames using dates?

Extra: below is an example of what my dataframe looks like

[image]

Thank you for your time!
-Bojan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_some = df_all.loc['2021-08-04 19:05:00':'2021-08-05 19:10:00']
```

Thank you Kyle Parsons!

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates':pd.date_range(datetime(2020,1,1), datetime(2021,1,1)),
                        'col_1': np.random.randint(1,1000, 367),
                        'col_2': np.random.randint(1,1000, 367)})


df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
df = df[(df.index > datetime(2020,6,1)) & (df.index < (datetime(2020, 8, 1)))]
print(df)
```